# Unable to click on tabs in Firefox unless I press Command-Q

Tags: macos, firefox, browser-tabs, mouse-click

Why does clicking on tabs in Firefox sometimes fail until I hit cmd-Q, and then why does that not quit but instead make clicking on the tabs work, and how do I stop that behavior?

I'm running Firefox 3.5.5 on Mac OS X 10.5 and this has been happening for a while (with previous versions of FF as well). I can't forcibly reproduce the behavior, but every now and then (few days?) I just can't click on tabs or on the x's to close the tabs. I can still ctrl-tab between tabs, though. But if I press cmd-Q, instead of quitting, Firefox seems to seize for a second and then I can click on tabs and click to close them just fine. No clue why this is happening or how to stop it. And I do have tons of extensions installed, so it's plausible one of them is the problem..... Thanks.

Comment: what extensions?

Comment: Literally 30. New information though: this happens sometimes when a web page asks for access to my computer when it presents me with a form, and then I can also solve the problem by minimizing the window and then re-maximizing it (without the cmd-q business), which makes it a little less of a headache but still a curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to try is to start Firefox in Safe mode (no extensions), and see if the problem goes away.

If it is an extension problem, you can deactivate them in a binary search, to find the guilty extension.

Comment: It's a good idea in theory but the problem is that the behavior doesn't necessarily manifest even during an entire browsing session. So the absence of the behavior doesn't necessarily indicate that a turned-off extension is the culprit; it's possible that the behavior just isn't popping up for whatever reason it sometimes just doesn't pop up and not because I eliminated the responsible extension.

Comment: @Philip: Might be a good idea to turn off as many extensions as won't cripple you too much for a few days.

Comment: Or to use Google Chrome :)